# Android - How to limit a call for certain duration?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call, telephony, telephonymanager

I am creating android application which makes a call. I just want to drop or cancel a call after certain duration, like I want to make a call which automatically drop after 60 sec. Is this possible in android? Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*03362111904"));

    startActivity(callIntent);
}

private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
            // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Capturing the outgoing call in a `BroadcastReceiver` has been mentioned and is definitely the best way to do it if you want to end the call before dialing.

The only way to hang up that I've encountered so far, is to do so through Java [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29). As it is not part of the public API, you should *be careful to use it, and not rely upon it*. Any change to the internal composition of Android will effectively break your application.

[Prasanta Paul's blog demonstrates](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html) how it can be accomplished, which I have summarized below.

Obtaining the `ITelephony` object:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
try {
    // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
    // ITelephony getter
    Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService =
            (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG,
            "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
}
```

Ending the call:

```
telephonyService.endCall();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The code you have provided is just cancel the call but how can I cancel the call after 60 sec call dialed ?

Comment: you can add your logic in `BroadcastReceiver` to get call information

Comment: You can set a timer or a handler with postdelayed to end the call after 60 secs.

Comment: you can accept the answer if you got solution so that in future other can get assistance.